# tableview default selected cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use below code to show core data table in UITableView

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9mds.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0tCF.png)

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: my table view is bind with NSManagedObjects (groups), now i want to select a group by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you know the index of the one you want to select?
It's a little unclear what the desired criteria is for finding the correct `groups`

Otherwise you'll need a for loop to find it in your fetchedResults

```
 // for loop around _group to find the index

NSInteger index = -1;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [_group count]; i++) {

    NSManagedObject *groups = [_group objectAtIndex:i];

    if (selectedgroup != nil && groups == selectedgroup) {

        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index != -1)
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

I also assumed you only have 1 section, as you were pulling out managed objects for indexPath.row

Comment: i pass "selectedgroup" from another view controller to group tableviewcontroller and i want check in group tableviewcontroller  if "selectedgroup" exist then select that in group tableview in  view did appear

Comment: sorry my fault it work great, thank you so much Magoo